# Call to undefined function factory() in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have two factories which goes here:

**CourseFactory.php**:

```
protected $model = Course::class;

public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
            'body' => $this->faker->paragraph(5),
            'price' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1000,10000),
            'image' => $this->faker->imageUrl(),
        ];
    }
```

And **EpisodeFactory.php**:

```
protected $model = Episode::class;

public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
            'body' => $this->faker->paragraph(5),
            'videoUrl' => 'https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        ];
    }
```

And then on **DatabaseSeeder.php**:

```
public function run()
    {
        $user = factory(App\Models\User::class)->create();
        factory(\App\Models\Course::class , 5)->create(['user_id' => $user->id ])->each(function ($course) {
            factory(\App\Models\Episode::class, rand(6 , 20))->make()->each(function ($episode , $key) use ($course){
                $episode->number = $key +1;
                $course->episodes()->save($episode);
            });
        });
    }
```

But when I want to run `php artisan db:seed`, I get this error:

> **Call to undefined function Database\Seeders\factory()**
>
> at
> C:\Users\POUYA\Desktop_MACOSX\laravel-api\database\seeders\DatabaseSeeder.php

The error message is referring to this line:

`$user = factory(App\Models\User::class)->create();`

Meaning that I didn't use `factory` in a proper way.

So how to call `factory` in a correct way?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

**UserFactory.php**:

```
protected $model = User::class;

public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Where is the user factory?

Comment: @DevBF I just added it to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In laravel 8, the way to call factory is changed. Please look at the [changelog](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#model-factory-classes)

Here's the way to call it [now](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#persisting-models)

So in your case, change your code to:

```
public function run()
    {
        $user = \App\Models\User::factory()->create();
        \App\Models\Course::factory()->count(5)->create(['user_id' => $user->id ])->each(function ($course) {
            \App\Models\Episode::factory()->count(rand(6 , 20))->make()->each(function ($episode , $key) use ($course){
                $episode->number = $key +1;
                $course->episodes()->save($episode);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank u, but there is a syntax error on this line: `$user = App\Models\User::factory->create();`

Comment: Try now, just like any other eloquent, you have to call it as a function `App\Models\User::factory()->create();`. I have edited my answer

Comment: It seems correct, but now I get `Class 'Database\Seeders\App\Models\User' not found
` error :(

Comment: Try again :), I have edited the answer. put backslash in front of the `\App\Models...`, its trying to look to the current namespace. I suggest you use `use App\Models\User` at the top of your file so you can just call `User::factory()`. As well as for the rest of the class